# Can't get HMAC Authentication working with API

Tags: node.js, hmac

I'm trying to authenticate using HMAC with the [LocalBitcoins API](https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/).

Here is the authentication written in Python:

```
  message = str(nonce) + hmac_auth_key + relative_path + get_or_post_params_urlencoded
  signature = hmac.new(hmac_auth_secret, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
```

And the parameters to create the HMAC message:

```
Nonce. A 63 bit positive integer, for example unix timestamp as milliseconds.

HMAC authentication key. This is the first one of a key/secret pair.

Relative path, for example /api/wallet/.

GET or POST parameters in their URL encoded format, for example foo=bar&baz=quux.
```

Here is how I am building the HMAC:

```
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
var key = config.key;
var secret = config.secret;
var nonce = milliseconds.toString()


var message = nonce + key + 'api/myself';

var hmac_digest = crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret).update(message).digest('hex').toUpperCase();
```

The signature is sent via 3 HTTP Headers. The options for the call to the api/myself method looks like such (using request):

```
{ url: 'https://localbitcoins.com/api/myself',
  method: 'GET',
  headers:
   { 'Apiauth-Key': 'my api key',
     'Apiauth-Nonce': 1439925212276,
     'Apiauth-Signature': 'the created signature' },
  timeout: 5000 }
```

And the request:

```
var req = request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

But everytime I get the following error message:

```
{ error:
   { message: 'HMAC authentication key and signature was given, but they are invalid.',
     error_code: 41 } }
```

I've tried lots of different combinations in testing but can't get anything to work. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, have you tried using OAuth for authentication instead?

Comment: I haven't looked at it. Would still super prefer HMAC at this point.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my path was wrong.

`/path` needed to be `/path/`, which I found out through working with a working Python implementation.

The package is up and running now here: https://github.com/mrmayfield/localbitcoins-node

Answer (score 0):

I think that `(new Date).getTime();` is not creating a 63 bit integer.  Per Dr. Axel's [post](http://www.2ality.com/2014/02/time-values.html).  JavaScript has 53 bit integers plus a sign.

Comment: If I use `(new Date).getTime()*1000` I get the same error. Not sure how to check the bit value of integers either.

Comment: I don't think you can make a js integer to 63 bits.  [max int mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Is there no way to send a 63 bit integer then? I'm looking at using this library: https://github.com/broofa/node-int64  . Will this allow me to send a 63 bit integer or will it blow up as soon as I try and send the variable as a raw header?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it looks like it would blow up when you try to get the value because it will register as infinity.  It seems as though only the octet representation is non-volatile.

Comment: The thing though is that the integer doesn't need to be completely precise. Can't I spoof a 63 bit integer just by adding numbers, regardless of it is precisely what is sent to the server?